# httpclient is superslow (htmlunit 2.24 )

Tags: java, spring, httpclient, htmlunit

hi i am a webprogrammer in korea and i developed a method for
crawling lot's of merchandise informations.
i made it in our webapplication(made by spring). and it is activated by requesting specific url that is down below

@RequestMapping(value = "/naverCrawlJobAjax", produces = "application/json; charset=utf8")

it works fine when i activate it in my local tomcat server.
but when i request the url of the actual running server, it is stucked
with this method
(org/apache/http/impl/client/InternalHttpClient.doExecute(HttpHost, HttpRequest, HttpContext))

it also works in the actual running server. but too slow to use it....

any help? T.T

```
    //code start
    WebClient webClient =  new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_45);//maybe stucked in here
    webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false);
    webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
    webClient.getOptions().setUseInsecureSSL(true);
    webClient.getOptions().setCssEnabled(false);
    webClient.addRequestHeader("Accept-Language", "ko-KR,ko;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4, value");
    webClient.addRequestHeader("Accept-Charset", "windows-949,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3");
    webClient.getCookieManager().setCookiesEnabled(true);
    webClient.setJavaScriptTimeout(50000);

    String result = "S";
    String url = "https://adcenter.shopping.naver.com/member/login/form.nhn";
    HtmlPage page;
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
    obj.put("resultCode", result);
    obj.put("httpClientVer", HttpClientBuilder.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation());
```

Comment: There are many possible explanations for this.  One is that the site you are trying to crawl has implemented something to stop you crawling their site.  I don't read / speak Korean, but when I pointed Google Translate at the site's Terms & Conditions page, it seems to forbid automatically harvesting information from it.

Comment: maybe not, because it works fine in my local tomcat server and actual running server(but slow)

Comment: Actually, maybe yes .... because it runs slow on the actual running server.  Consider that they could be trying to defeat you by **deliberately** slowing down your connection, etc.  It is not hard to do.

Comment: OMG.. thx for ur answer. is it possble for them to find out the enviroment between my local pc and real server?